# Calculating values contained in a text field

Tags: excel, vba

I have a description field within my data set which includes a list of product names and directly after each name I have a quantity value which is stored within square brackets.

e.g. 
Product one [2]
Product two [1]

I'm looking to extract the figures from within the square brackets and add them together.

I can find the first value by using a MID/FIND formula but can't figure out how to look up and calculate multiple quantities?

I cannot split up my data due to the large number of products contained on some records.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide further example of the data, your actual code/formula and what exactly is the problem you are facing? When you say "*add them together*" you mean you want 2+1 = 3 or 2 & 1

Comment: Sorry should of been more specific, yes 2 + 1 =3.

Comment: As Victor mentioned, we need more information. Is your code able to step through all cells in `description` column? If so please provide the code you have

Comment: You could use Data->Text to Columns and use [ as the delimiter. Then do a find and a replace on the ]'s and replace with nothing, this will remove them. You will then have your product names in one column and quantities in a second which would be easier to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a cleaner method but this would work (Assuming you're looking at a single cell):

```
Public Function SumBrackets(rngSource As Range)
Dim strData As String
Dim dblSum As Double
Dim lngBracketStart As Long
Dim lngBracketEnd As Long
strData = rngSource.Value
Do While InStr(1, strData, "[") <> 0
    lngBracketStart = InStr(1, strData, "[")
    lngBracketEnd = InStr(1, strData, "]")
    dblSum = dblSum + Mid(strData, lngBracketStart + 1, lngBracketEnd - lngBracketStart - 1)
    strData = Mid(strData, lngBracketEnd + 1, Len(strData) - lngBracketEnd)
Loop

SumBrackets = dblSum
End Function
```